# dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap changes the type of my variable to map[string]interface{}

Tags: go, types

**Background**

I am trying to Unmarshal an item returned by `dynamodb.GetItem` into an object, which type I do not know at that place.
For this I have a function `emptyItemConstructor` which returns a new object of the desired type.

**Question**

I have a function like this:

```
func GetItem(emptyItemConstructor func() interface{}) interface{} {
  myItem := emptyItemConstructor()
  fmt.Printf("Type is: %T\n", myItem)
  _ = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item, &myItem)
  fmt.Printf("Type now is: %T\n", myItem)
}
```

and I am passing this function for `emptyItemConstructor`:

```
func constructor() MyDynamoDBItemType {
    return MyDynamoDBItemType{}
}
```

The output of the function is:

```
Type is: MyDynamoDBItemType
Type now is: map[string]interface
```

Why is UnmarshalMap changing the type of myItem?

Comment: You are passing a pointer to an interface to UnmarshalMap. Don't do that. Change constructor to return  `*MyDynamoDBItemType`.

Comment: What is the definition of `MyDynamoDBItemType`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of variable `myItem` is `interface{}`, and the type of `UnmarshalMap` input param is `interface{}` too. There is no comparison of underlying types when assigning values

A example is as follows:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func Item() interface{} {
    return struct {
        Name string
    }{Name: "poloxue"}
}

func ItemMap(item *interface{}) {
    *item = map[string]interface{}{
        "Name": "poloxue",
    }
}

func main() {
    m := Item()
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", m)
    ItemMap(&m)
    fmt.Printf("%T\n", m)
}
```

If you want to unmarshal map to struct , try [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package?

Answer (score 3):

Your function is far too complex. Stop trying to force a "generics" mindset into Go. Just do this:

```
func GetItem(i interface{}) {
  _ = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item, &i)
}
```

But don't ignore errors:

```
func GetItem(i interface{}) error {
  return dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item, &i)
}
```

But then you don't need your function at all... just use

```
dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(item, &i)
```

as intended.